# Just list one product variation

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, commerce

I'm developing a videogame store with Commerce (I'm n00b in Drupal), so for example I'm adding a new game "GTA V", GTA has versions to XBOX360 and PS3, so I'm trying to create the product and add two variations for PS and XBOX with different prices and some stuff, but I don't need a product page where the user selects PS or XBOX version, because I'm splitting my site by consoles, so if the user is in XBOX section, I need to list only the XBOX variation and not the PS variation.

I'm trying to achieve this because I don't wanna repeat myself with description, videos, etc of video games, so in the "GTA V" example I will write just one description and not two (for PS and XBOX) that will be the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use views to filter on the catalog pages for product variations if they are set. You should take a look at http://www.drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/products the guide will help you create product variations, you can then create a view for the catalog, you can then create a exposed filter (lets the users change the filter value) for product variation so they user can select PS3 or XBOX and get only those products on the filter. But if you went to that page, you would still need to select "PS3" or "XBOX" to place a order.

Comment: what you recommend is what I'm doing right now, but is not what I'm trying to achieve, because I wanna treat those variations like individual product page.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by individual product pages?

Comment: If have GTA V with two variations, PS3 and XBOX 360, I need to list those variations like a full product page (full content view) and avoid the "variation select" by the user. So, the user enter to my website, select PS3 at top menu, go to games sections, click GTA V game and there is where I need to only show the PS3 variation of GTA V, so the user only need to click "Add to cart". It's redundant if the user select the PS3 variation in that page.